# renaming files to incremental values with correct digits

Tags: python, windows, powershell, rename

I would like to rename a list of pictures based on a root name being the directory name, (picture in this example) by padding the previous numbering with the appropriate of zeros based on the total number of files and increment. I was thinking of using Powershell or Python. Recommendations?

current 'C:\picture' directory contents

```
pic 1.jpg
...
pic 101.jpg
```

Result

```
picture 001.jpg
...
picture 101.jpg
```

Comment: I recommend you use python or powershell.  If you have some code I could probably help you with that too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's python solution:

```
import glob
import os

dirpath = r'c:\picture'
dirname = os.path.basename(dirpath)

filepath_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, 'pic *.jpg'))
pad = len(str(len(filepath_list)))
for n, filepath in enumerate(filepath_list, 1):
    os.rename(
        filepath,
        os.path.join(dirpath, 'picture {:>0{}}.jpg'.format(n, pad))
    )
```

- `pad` is calculated using file count `len(filepath_list)`:

  ```
  >>> len(str(100)) # if file count is 100
  3
  ```
- `'picture {:>0{}}.jpg'.format(99, 3)` is like `'picture {:>03}.jpg'.format(99)`. Format string `{:>03}` zero-pad(`0`), right-align(`>`) the input value (`99` in the following example).

  ```
  >>> 'picture {:>0{}}.jpg'.format(99, 3)
  'picture 099.jpg'
  >>> 'picture {:>03}.jpg'.format(99)
  'picture 099.jpg'
  ```

Documentation for the functions used:

- [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob)
- [os.path.basename](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)
- [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
- [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: It might be worth explaining how `'picture {:>0{}}.jpg'.format(n, pad)` works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

1. You already know how to traverse your directory
2. Access the file names in your script
3. Rename the files

Couple of Things to understand

1. Your file name has a format with the numbers padded with '0's if its less than a certain size, in your example if its less than 3. `str.format`, provides an elaborate format string specifier to achieve this
2. You need to know how to get the relevant portions of your file name to be reformatted as required
3. The formatting would vary ultimately based on number of files.

**Demo**

```
>>> no_of_files = 100
>>> no_of_digits = int(math.log10(no_of_files)) + 1
>>> format_exp = "pictures {{:>0{}}}.{{}}".format(no_of_digits)
>>> for fname in files:
    #Discard the irrelevant portion
    fname = fname.rsplit()[-1]
    print format_exp.format(*fname.split('.'))


pictures 001.jpg
pictures 002.jpg
pictures 010.jpg
pictures 100.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell solution:

```
$jpgs = Get-ChildItem C:\Picture\*.jpg
$numDigits = "$($jpgs.Length)".Length
$formatStr = "{0:$('0' * $numDigits)}"
$jpgs | Where {$_.BaseName -match '(\d+)'} | 
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.DirectoryName + '\' + $_.Directory.Name + ($formatStr -f [int]$matches[1]) + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to actually execute the rename if the preview you get with `-WhatIf` looks good.